Branches and branch cuts for $\sqrt{z^2-1}$
Is it possible to define a branch $f(z)$ of the function $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ on $\mathbb C \setminus [-1,1]$ such that $f(2)=\sqrt{3}$? If it is possible to define such a branch, can one give some kind of formula for it in terms of the principal branch of the square root? Is it easier to define a branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ on $\mathbb C \setminus ((- \infty, -1] \cup [1,\infty))$?

Re$(w) \geq 0 ~: ~w^2 = z^2 - 1.$

Let $g(z) = z \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}},$ where $\sqrt{}$ denotes the principal branch of the square root.
Then $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash [-1,1]$,  $g(2)=\sqrt{3}$ and $g^2(z) = z^2-1.$

Thank you very much, this is a really neat solution! Is this a general method how to approach such problems? Is there a place to read about things like this?

I'd like to give an alternative solution and explain a bit how to derive solutions.
To make this simpler, we will work in polar coordinates, looking for a function of the form $G(z) = r(z) e^{i\theta(z)}$ such that $G(z)^2 = z^2 - 1$, and $G(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1, 1]$.
Since $G(z)^2 = z^2 - 1$, any solution for $\theta(z)$ must satisfy:
$$2\theta \equiv \operatorname{Arg} (z^2 - 1) \pmod{2\pi}$$
($-\pi < \operatorname{Arg}z < \pi$ denotes the principal value of the argument).
The simplest solution is to let the two sides be equal, i.e. $\theta = \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Arg}(z^2 - 1)$. This is just $z \mapsto \sqrt{z^2 - 1}$, where $\sqrt{ }$ is the principal branch of the square root (the one that satisfies $\mathfrak{Re}(\sqrt{z}) > 0$). Note that this function is already holomorphic at $z = 2$, but it has discontinuities on the entire imaginary axis as well as $(-1, 1)$.
So the question is, what solution would remove the discontinuities on the imaginary axis?
The key is that the right side above, $\operatorname{Arg} (z^2 - 1)$, has range $(-\pi, \pi]$, which means $\theta$ is constrained to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. But we can replace the right side with something that ranges from $-2\pi$ to $2\pi$.
A natural idea would be $2\theta = \operatorname{Arg} (z + 1) + \operatorname{Arg} (z - 1)$, and you can verify that $\operatorname{Arg} (z + 1) + \operatorname{Arg} (z - 1) \equiv \operatorname{Arg} (z^2 - 1) \pmod{2\pi}$.
Then write the full function:
$$\sqrt{|z^2 - 1|}e^{i(\operatorname{Arg} (z + 1)/2 + \operatorname{Arg} (z - 1)/2)}$$
$$=\sqrt{|z + 1|}e^{i(\operatorname{Arg} (z + 1)/2)}\sqrt{|z - 1|}e^{i(\operatorname{Arg} (z - 1)/2)}$$
$$=\sqrt{z + 1} \sqrt{z - 1}$$
This function is continuous on the imaginary axis and only has discontinuities on $[-1, 1]$.
As a final note, the answer by C. Dubussy accomplishes the same thing but uses a different equivalence: $\operatorname{Arg} z^2 \equiv 2\operatorname{Arg} z \pmod{2\pi}$. Hence we can add $2\operatorname{Arg} z - \operatorname{Arg} z^2$ to $\operatorname{Arg} (z^2 - 1)$ and get
$$2\theta = 2\operatorname{Arg} z + \operatorname{Arg}(z^2 - 1) - \operatorname{Arg} z^2$$
Which leads to that answer.
